# Unable to read from file in java even though file is in working directory

Tags: java, compiler-errors, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to read from a .txt file in java but I keep getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Here is my simple line of code.

```
public class Main {

private static Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("walking2.txt"));
}
```

Here is how my project looks like:
[image]

Comment: make sure the file isn't open elsewhere

Comment: `Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "JavaCodes/SyncSampling/walking2.txt"));`

Comment: You keep being told about an unhandled exception *by the compiler.* it isn't at all the same thing. You do need to understand whatbth error message actually says, and who produced it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this :

```
 new Scanner(new File("walking2.txt"));
```

throw a `FileNotFoundException`, so when you declare it as you do, where you exception should be gone?

Instead, you have to declare it inside a method or in a static block. for example :

```
private static Scanner s;
void methodName(){
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("walking2.txt"));
        //..your code
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

match better it to use [Try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure that the file is closed after your operations correctly.

```
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("walking2.txt"))) {
        //..your code
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```